# Laravel csrf token gives an error in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Guys I used `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in the head section. And I use ajax to submit some data to controller, and that works fine.

But I got one form in the same page to upload a image. When I submit data from that form laravel gives me a `TokenMismatchException` error in `in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)`. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Probably the problem is on line 68. Read [ask]

Comment: no it is not. Line 68 error is a common error. And thanks I will read How to Ask page. I'm in quite hurry :( because dead line is today

Comment: why are you addding it in the meta? why can't you submit it as a data param? `data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }} }",`

Comment: I did so according to the laravel documentation here,
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)
then I collected the value with 
 `var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

Answer (score 1):

For each request you send, if you use jQuer ajax you can get the value of token and pass it to data.

```
data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
```

Answer (score 0):

try put this inside your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add csrf-token into ajax request in page scope:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```